# Timepicker doesn't work in mvc project

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, timepicker

I'm trying to use timepicker from http://timepicker.co/ in my mvc project. I downloaded jquery.timepicker.min.js and jquery.timepicker.min.css and added it to my project. 
When I'm clicking in my input field nothing happened. Has anybody had the same problem and could share the way it could be fixed?

Comment: what is the error that u get in your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Timepicker is very Simple. Just Add the Timepicker script and css on your page.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="example" />
```

JavaScript :

```
$(function(){
   $('#example').timepicker(); 
});
```

JsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/rejzzp4x/

Comment: thanks!!! it's work

but now I have another problem: the input field with timepicker is on modal window and when i focus on that field with my mouse all options are placed under that modal window. What kind of problem is that?